# Read Oracle redo (transaction) log files in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to monitor (in near real-time) the log files for Oracle DB so I can see Delete/Create/Update changes against tables.

I've been unable to find suitable documentation or example source. Does anyone have an example of how to do this, or suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Given that the internal structure of those files is propriatary, I seriously doubt you will find it documented anywhere.  I'd question the usefulness of what you propose.

Comment: For your requirements you may have a look at [Audits](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [logminer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-logminer-utility.html#GUID-3417B738-374C-4EE3-B15C-3A66E01AE2B5), it allows you to do that in sql, which you can try accessing from c#